# jQuery Draggable not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My jQuery drag and drop environment in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3Tg/) is not behaving as expected: each initial div should be freely draggable and the 'adddiv' button will add another draggable div. They should not stop being draggable, they should be able to be dragged again not freeze in position.

I've used  `.draggable()` to enable dragging and also report positioning to the console and `.append()` to add more divs.

Right now after the initial move, they freeze, but the appended divs can be moved again.

Comment: There is another problem with the `add` functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the attribute values dynamically, like -

```
  $("#adddiv").click(function() {

       var lastid = $("#set div").last().attr('data-need')
       lastid = parseInt(lastid) + 1;

       $('#set').append('<div id="' + lastid+ '" data-need="' +lastid + '"></div>');
       $( "#" + lastid ).draggable();
 });
```

There may be more concise ways to do this. Still, this works on your jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3Tg/ , for more than 1 dynamically appended blocks, without freezing.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your issue.

You were creating a div with the same id '6' each time you clicked on add div.

```
$("#adddiv").click(function() {
  $('<div></div>').draggable().appendTo($('#set'));

});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3Tg/1/

Comment: Thank you, but the original divs freeze once dragging has stopped. Still can't 'pick them back up again'

Comment: @user1202278 : Are you sure about that? It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use class instead of id. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3Tg/3/).

```
$('#set').append('<div class="6" data-need="6"></div>');
```